# App engine abort mapreduce shard

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, sharding

I kicked off a mapreduce process which is unfortunately not Aborting and has been chewing through all my CPU. Does anyone know of a way to stop this?

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to purge the queue used by mapreduce

Comment: thanks for your answer. Mapreduce is running through the google provided api so I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this. Can you provide any more detail?

Comment: @Richard: I understand your point of view, but I guess you have already tried to use the abort signal. So i make a purge in the queue used by mapreduce. Every next workers are not executed.

Comment: You can clear the task queues easily enough in the Admin console / Developer Console. I don't think that's it though. That doesn't push the abort command through.

Comment: Update: In addition to clearing the current tasks, you need to pause the task queue for several minutes, and clear any new tasks that accumulate.